# My AspDotNet Core SignalR application is working correctly in localhost but not working in Azure. I don't want to use Azure signalR service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-signalr

I have simple push notification SignalR application and and I have to host it on Azure, it is working fine in my localhost but  on azure it is not working. Below is the code. this is Microservice solution so some of the config are related to microservice.

```
public class Startup
    {
        private const string SwaggerApiVersion = "v1";
        private const string SwaggerApiTitle = "Messaging Microservice API";
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication")
                    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication", null);
            services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationRepository, AuthenticationRepository>();

            Utility.Swagger.SwaggerConfig.ConfigureService(services, SwaggerApiVersion, SwaggerApiTitle,
                Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml"));

            services.AddSignalR();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            Tracking.SetConfiguration();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<NotificationHub.NotificationHub>("/notificationHub");
            });

            app.UseMvc();
            Utility.Swagger.SwaggerConfig.ConfigureApplication(app, SwaggerApiVersion, SwaggerApiTitle);

            Tracking.TrackEvent(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name + ".Started");
        }
    }
```

Below is Hub Class.

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(List<string> userIds)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", userIds);
    }

    public async Task SendToAll(string name, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("SendToAll", name, message);
    }
}
```

Actually connection is not establishing from my react client and I am not able to invoke hub methods (SendMessage, SendToAll).

Below is react client connection code.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    let url = Config['MessagingMicroservice'].replace(/\bapi\b(?!.*?\bapi\b)/, 'notificationHub');
    const hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(url).build();

    this.setState({ hubConnection }, () => {
        this.state.hubConnection
            .start()
            .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
            .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));

        this.state.hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', (userIds) => {
            const usrIds = `${userIds}`;
            if (usrIds.includes(this.state.userId)) {
                this.getNotificationCount(this.state.userId);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

And I am getting below errors.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://isambard-dev.capitawfm.co.uk:19081/IsambardServiceFabric/MessagingMicroservice/notificationHub/?id=OcLN9AYHOVp8Hr4t3mPVPA' 
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 504

https://isambard-dev.capitawfm.co.uk:19081/IsambardServiceFabric/MessagingMicroservice/notificationHub/?id=jcEzEb0coVTp51hQeFlzOw
Error: Failed to start the transport 'ServerSentEvents': Error: Error occurred
```

Comment: Resonants to this question will probably need more information than "it's not working"

Comment: Please update your question to be a bit more specific. As @CalC sais "it's not working" isn't enough. Also, please add _relevant_ code. Commented code, or config for something completely unrelated only makes it harder for others to help you. Please refer to [mcve]

Comment: Actually connection is not establishing from my react client and I am not able to invoke hub methods (SendMessage, SendToAll).

Comment: @PraveenDeewan how are you hosting in Azure?

Comment: yes. I am hosting it to Azure and my challenge is I am not able to establish connection with Hub.